# Joining two tables. Which SQL is right?

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g

I am trying to check whether DAY values are stored at Sales ID level. They are in two different tables. I have created two different queries. Could someone tell me which one is right.

```
select S.sales_id,count(D.ID) from 
  W_SALES_ORDER_LINE_F S,
   W_DAY_D D
    where 
  D.ID = S.SCHEDULE_ID
    group by S.sales_id ;
```

OR

```
 select S.sales_id,count(D.ID) from 
  W_SALES_ORDER_LINE_F S join
   W_DAY_D D
    on 
  D.ID = S.SCHEDULE_ID
    group by S.sales_id ;
```

I am trying to improve the performance. So I want to know based on their performances and runtime etc.

Comment: It's the one that gives you the right answer.

Comment: @Dilip Both queries are the same but with the different syntax. The latter is more preferable.

Comment: What do you mean by "right"?  Is one or both not working?  What are you expecting to get vs. what are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are equivalent, but the latter query is preferable as it conforms to the newer ANSI-92 SQL standard.

Answer (score 1):

Both queries will yield the same results.